# Discover all PSmethods of an object

Tags: powershell, methods

When I run this command:

```
$psise.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.SubMenus | GM
```

The result does not show me the methods `Remove` & `Removeat` which I know do exist. So how do we discover all the methods available to an object?

I have run `GM -force` but still don't see the `Remove` methods. Are these methods being generated dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collections are enumerated, when passed by pipeline. What you see by

```
$psise.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.SubMenus | GM
```

is a members of `SubMenus` collection's elements not collection itself. To get members of collection you need write it like this:

```
,$psise.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.SubMenus | GM
```

or this:

```
GM -InputObject $psise.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.SubMenus
```